# Nuxt 3 - useFetch breaking vitest tests

Tags: server-side-rendering, vite, nuxtjs3, vitest

I have recently added `useFetch` to all of my pages so I can fetch my CMS content on the server-side but since then all my `vitest` tests have broke and I can't figure out the issue.

```
// Footer.vue - script
<script lang="ts" setup>
const config = useRuntimeConfig()

const { data: content } = await useFetch(`${config.STRAPI_URL}/api/footer?populate=deep`)
</script>
```

```js
// Footer.spec.js
describe('Footer.vue', () => {
  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(Footer, {
      global: {
        stubs: ['nuxt-link'],
      },
    })
  })

  it('is mounted', () => {
    expect(wrapper.findComponent(Footer).exists()).toBe(true)
  })
});
```

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
  <div>
    <nav />

    <nuxt-page />

    <suspense>
      <footer />
    </suspense>
  </div>
```

Warning:
`[Vue warn]: Component <Footer>: setup function returned a promise, but no <Suspense> boundary was found in the parent component tree. A component with async setup() must be nested in a <Suspense> in order to be rendered at <Footer ref="VTU_COMPONENT" >`

When console logging `wrapper.vm` is just comes back as an empty object
Also unable to auto import nuxt 3 composables into my tests

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this Vue warning you need to wrap the component with `suspense` component in your test.

```
const AsyncFooter = defineComponent({
  components: { AFooter },
  template: '<Suspense><AFooter/></Suspense>',
})
const wrapper = mount(AsyncFooter)
```